# Using chrome.downloads.acceptDanger from background page context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Invoking `chrome.downloads.acceptDanger` API method from background page context just causes this error:

> Javascript execution context is not visible (tab, window, popup bubble)

What am I doing wrong? How to properly call this API from a background page?

Comment: Seems like some undocumented restriction.

Comment: Issue to fix documentation: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [an undocumented restriction](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482443).

Apparently, `acceptDanger` works by displaying a dialog to the user, and that dialog is tied to a visible page.

Which means that a background page *cannot* call this method currently.

Chrome extension samples call this in the context of a popup.

Comment: That restriction makes this api useless. Thanks for your answer. You, Sir, are awesome.

Comment: I tried to invoke `chrome.downloads.drag` from background page, and it raised the same error. Does the same "undocumented restriction" apply to it as well?